# Transaction hash has different block number on my ethereum ropsten testnet node

Tags: ropsten, testnets

I have an ethereum ropsten testnet node,  syncing status is false but i checked for the block number then I got the block number ahead of the actual current height. I then checked   the transaction hash of a recent transaction on etherscan and when matched the same transaction hash on my ethereum testnet node, then it showing all the data same as actual except the block number. On my node, block number for a transaction is different while on etherscan it is different block number for the same transaction hash. I really don't have any idea for this issue so please guide me for the same.

current status of my node : [image]

Current Height on etherscan : [image]

transaction hash details on my node : [image]

same transaction hash status on etherscan : https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x1f4e4b28677048b6318c371e3b0e53677942616dc6f67caea2a810a536c0e753

Answer (score 0):

Your Geth version is outdated-you are likely on a "wrong", forked chain.
There was a consensus issue between nodes on Ropsten which was fixed in v1.10.6.

Even then, you may be on a "double" forked chain because of an exploit on nodes >v1.10.7. Update your node and you should be good.